# SQL Server : join all left table and repeat right

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to join tables in a following way:

Table A:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Table B:

```
A
B
```

The result table should be:

```
1 A
2 B
3 A
4 B
5 A
```

Do you have any ideas how to do this?

Comment: why would you need such a query?

Comment: Use modulo, if a col is odd, then A, if even, then B.

Comment: Expanding on @vkp's comment, what is the original problem statement? This smells like the wrong approach to the original (or, perhaps, any) problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming worst case, the column in table A is not a sequence without gaps and the number of rows in table B is not known in advance, you must apply a ROW_NUMBER on both tables and then join on a MODULO:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM
 (
   SELECT col1,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) -1 AS rn
   FROM tableA
 ) AS A
JOIN 
 (
   SELECT col2,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col2) -1 AS rn
   FROM tableB
 ) AS B
ON A.rn % (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableB) = B.rn
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
select A.nr, case when (A.nr%2=0) then b2.chr else b3.chr end letter
from A, B b2, B b3
where b2.chr = 'A' and b3.chr = 'B'
```